# Constructor with nearly 1000 Parameters

Tags: hibernate, struts2, multiple-columns

One of my table contains nearly 1000 columns. I'm creating a struts2-hibernate application.

So when creating class based upon the table i'm having the constructor with nearly 1000 parameters.
does this creates any problem ... since I'm using Hibernate

Comment: since you are using you hibernate, you will need a [default constructor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-pojo-constructor)

Comment: 1000 Parameters! This won't create any syntax challenges, but may cause a lots of other problems such as but not limited to usability challenges.

Comment: 1000 columns in a table ? I guess that database could be normalized A BIT... O_o

Comment: A ctor with 1k arguments is a joke. Why bother? You should switch that to a fluent interface/builder pattern at the very least. Completely unusable by any metric. You're going to run in to performance issues unless you're very specific in what columns you return from queries, and that has nothing to do with Hibernate.

Comment: I can't decide whether this is a really sad question or an excellent troll.

Comment: As @AndreaLigios mentioned already you should start rethinking your schema first and only then try to fix the problem with too many arguments, even if Java itself will allow you to do that I don't think you should go this way

Comment: And +1 for @StevenBenitez :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using you hibernate, you will need a [default constructor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-pojo-constructor), if you have that I don't see any problems with having a constructor will 1000 arguments.

Comment: @user2018186 Performance i don't think will be a problem, but usability will nill. I can't think using a constructor with 1000 argumensts